# Which is an appropriate way to use the same expression to evaluate multiple directives?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-changedetection

I'm currently building a table which has a particular column where I need to proccess de data a bit to get the actual value I want to display; the value in the row's object is an ID number, so I then have to look for that ID inside an array of objects I have in a variable.

Like this:

```
findIndustry(industry: string) {
if (this.industries.find(x => x._id === parseInt(industry, 10))) {
  const industryResult = this.industries.find(x => x._id === parseInt(industry, 10));
  return `${industryResult.category} | ${industryResult.subcategory}`;
}
  return '(Not Set)';
}
```

After getting the result I can just display it on the table like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="parentName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Industry </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client" class="industry-cell">{{ findIndustry(client.industry) }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

But now comes the issue; based on the returned value, I want to show a `title` attribute, and I also want to add an `ngClass` directive to show the text in grey color when `(Not Set)` is the value:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="parentName">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Industry </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client"
         [ngClass]="findIndustry(client.industry) === '(Not Set)' ? 'text-muted' : ''"
         class="industry-cell"
         [title]="findIndustry(client.industry)">{{ findIndustry(client.industry) }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

I've read that using function calls in Angular templates is a bad idea, since it would run the function on every change detection, which can be **a lot** of times; I'm wondering what would be an efficient way to avoid running the function so many times, or even better just avoid using the function at all; I do need that same value to apply different properties, that's the only reason I'm using it on every directive and attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated, **having a function in your html is a very bad idea...**

Below is an article about how a function is called in the html

> #### Angular’s Digest Cycle
>
> The digest cycle is how Angular’s auto-update magic works – it’s the reason that typing into an input box automatically updates anything that refers to its value.
> When the digest cycle runs, it effectively redraws everything that might have changed on the page.
> Angular uses some tricks to find “everything that might have changed”, and the main technique is watchers. These watchers are created automatically when you use directives like `ng-if` and `ng-class`, and when you use bindings like `{{ yourBindingHere }}`. 
> Each one of those things registers a watcher. **When Angular’s digest cycle runs, every watcher is asked to update its state**. In the case of ng-class, it will re-run the function bound to it, to see if anything needs to change. **This is why your controller function runs multiple times, and it’ll run again each time something changes on the page.**
> Source [Controller Function Is Executed Multiple Times](https://daveceddia.com/controller-function-executed-multiple-times/)

### Reactive Programming to the rescue

Angular comes preinstalled with `rxjs` by default. We can implement the power of `Observables` to solve this problem.

We can implement something like

- Define an observable with the data
- Define another observable to track industry id
- Combine the two `Obsevables`
- Subscribe to the resultant `Observable`
- Define a way to trigger change in the industry id

#### Define an observable with the data

On many occasions this would be simply a response from an http request

```typescript
industries$ = this.http.get<IIndustries[]>('some/api')
```

We can also generate an observable using `from` and `of` operators from `rxjs`

```typescript
industries: IIndustries[] = [{ ... }, { ... }, ...]
industries$ = of(this.industries)
```

#### Define another observable to track industry id

Next step is to define a way to track the selected industry. I will use a `BehaviorSubject` that will emit a value on initial load and every time we call the `next()` function on the `Subject`

```typescript
selectedIdSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1) // By default 1 will be selected
selectedId$ = this.selectedIdSubject$.asObservable()
```

#### Combine the two `Obsevables`

Next we need to combine the two `Observables`. We will use `combineLatest` from `rxjs`
From the official documentation

> This operator is best used when you have multiple, long-lived observables that rely on each other for some calculation or determination. 
> Source [Why use combineLatest?](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest#why-use-combinelatest)

```typescript
industry$ = combineLatest([this.industries$, this.selectedId]).pipe(
  map(([industries, industry]) => {
   if (industries.find(x => x._id === parseInt(industry, 10))) {
     const industryResult = industries.find(x => x._id === parseInt(industry, 10));
     return `${industryResult.category} | ${industryResult.subcategory}`;
   }
     return '(Not Set)';
   }
 })
)
```

We are piping the `Observable` stream and using `map` operator from `rxjs/operators` to transform the data

#### Almost Done, Subscribe to the resultant `Observable`

We will the `async` pipe to perform this purpose

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="parentName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Industry </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client" class="industry-cell">{{ industry$ | async }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

#### Finally... Define a way to trigger change in the industry id

To trigger change of the selected item, we simply call the next method on the `Subject`

```typescript
changeSelectedId (id) {
  this.selectedIdSubject$.next(id)
}
```

With the above approach, angular change detection will only be triggered when `changeSelectedId ()` function is called

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is save it in a big object like so:

```
findIndustry() {
//
 this.object[x._id] =  `${industryResult.category} | ${industryResult.subcategory}`;
//
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="parentName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Industry </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client" class="industry-cell">{{ object[client._id] }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

I hope it isnt too abstract (if you had a stackblitz implementation it would help).